# HOW to get article content from many urls webpages

Tags: java, html, url, web-scraping, jsoup

I have searched more than anything for  correct solution still i couldn't fix.
Please look on this & help me.

```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.BufferedWriter;
   import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;

   import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
   import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
   import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
   import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

   public class NewClass {


   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


   Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://tamilblog.ishafoundation.org").get();
         Elements section = doc.select("section#content");
  Elements article = section.select("article");
  for (Element a : article) {
    System.out.println("Title : \n" + a.select("a").text());
    System.out.println("Article summary: \n" + a.select("div.entry-summary").text());

  }

  }
}
```

I have the above code for getting article and its contents from an single page.

```
   Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://tamilblog.ishafoundation.org").get();
```

I want to do this for several websites.

In this line or using some iteration i want to apply my code for several webpages say 500+.
And i want to save it in separate text document under its article title and its contents.

I am new to coding so i could not find the correct code.

I was doing this code for past two months to create my code.

Answer (score 0):

For starter you can do something like this,

```
String[] urls={"http://tamilblog.ishafoundation.org","url2","url3"};//your 500 urls wil be stored here, 

    for(String url: urls){
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements section = doc.select("section#content");
        Elements article = section.select("article");
        for (Element a : article) {
            System.out.println("Title : \n" + a.select("a").text());
            System.out.println("Article summary: \n" + a.select("div.entry-summary").text());
        }
    }
```